# The Suggestion component on 5E's Guards and Wards: Does it fire only once?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

One of the options within the [Guards and Wards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guards-and-wards) Spell is the ability to place a Suggestion spell that says, "You select an area of up to 5 feet square, and any creature that enters or passes through the area receives the suggestion mentally."

Does this sub-spell only fire once, or for *every* creature that enters the area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every creature. This because there isn’t actually a spell that ‘fires’, there’s the ‘magical effect’ *of the spell*. So if there’s no spell that ‘fires’, then it seems logical that the effect should affect every creature with the wording. It says that

> ‘*any* creature that enters or passes through the area receives the suggestion mentally’

not that ‘any creature *can* be affected by the single firing’. That is already obvious by the text of suggestion:

> You suggest a course of activity (limited to a sentence or two) and magically influence a creature you can see...

So any creature can already be affected, so if that was all they were intending to convey, it would be extraneous. So it’s every creature that passes through.

Hope that helps!